# How can I get MySqlCommand to play nicely with .NET Core?

Tags: mysql, wpf, .net-core

I've got a .NET Framework program that I'm trying to run on .NET Core. It uses MySql 4.5. When I try and open a connection:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringToDB);
conn.Open();
```

the connection string :

> server=123.45.67;user id=yourusernamehere;password=yourpasswordhere;database=yourusernamehere;port=1234
> it crashes on the conn.Open() line with this exception:

```
WpfApp2 Error: 0 : 'Windows-1252' is not a supported encoding name. 
For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method. (Parameter 'name')
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in MySql.Data.dll An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
'Windows-1252' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
```

I'm out of my depth -- can anyone shed light on this, and how to get around it?

Comment: and what is the sanitized content of connectionStringToDB

Comment: You didn't provide enough information. where the 'Windows-1252'  can come from.and i am still not seeing it

Comment: It crashes on the conn.Open() line.

Comment: it is confusing because MySql 4.5. doesn't exist.  and mysql uses its connector, which also doesn't has a 4.5

Comment: Downloading Connector/NET 8.0.21 -- the architecture independent zip file on Oracle's site -- yields a folder labeled 4.5.2, with MySQL.Data.dll (among others).

Comment: ah good. still i don't get how you get the encoding from windows in your connection. Did you follow some tutorial.